# Spock: how can I mock a list of objects which return the object I have

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a list of objects, let it be integers:

```
list = [1, 3, 8]
```

I need a list of objects which in fact are PROVIDERS of these integers. I.e.:

```
providersList = [p1.getInteger() = 1, p2.getInteger() = 3, p3.getInteger() = 8] //pseudo code
```

How can I code it?

UPDATE

Sorry, looks like I was a little bit confusing. This is one of my first experiences with Spock so I may confuse the terms and ideas.

I want to mock a list of objects. Each object has its own methods, of course. The test will call only one method of that object. I dont need to implement it because I know what exactly returns this method. And these return values are stored in some list which I already have.

I.e. I need to mock a list of objects [p1, p2, p3] where each call to object.getInteger() returns some integer I already know, and I have a list of these integers: [i1, i2, i3]: p1.getInteger() = i1 etc.

How can I mock list of [p1, p2, p3] with the help of list [i1, i2, i3] ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: You mean like `[providersList = [{->1}, {->3}, {->8}]`?  I too am confused

Comment: providersList = [p1, p2, p3]; Then do providersList.get(0).getInteger()?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I have updated the question. It may be very simple, I am just starting with Spock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just try:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def 'some spec'() {
        given:    
        def mocks = [1, 2, 3].collect { i -> GroovyMock(SomeClass) {
             getInteger() >> i
           } 
        }

        expect:
        mocks*.getInteger().containsAll([1,2,3])
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    Integer getInteger() {
        0
    }
}
```